# Updating of R 3.5.3 to 4.0.2 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (bionic)

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, repository, r

I have been trying to move from this version for a while, however all attempts have failed.
The steps I am following:

```
sudo apt-get remove r-base r-base-dev
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/'
```

output:

```
Err:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/grass/grass-stable/ubuntu bionic Release     
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
```

after:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
```

output:

```
--recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
gpg: clave 51716619E084DAB9: "Michael Rutter <marutter@gmail.com>" sin cambios
gpg: Cantidad total procesada: 1
gpg:              sin cambios: 1
```

after:

```
sudo apt update
```

output:

```
Err:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/grass/grass-stable/ubuntu bionic Release     
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
```

after:

```
sudo apt install r-base r-base-core r-recommended
```

output:

```
r-recommended : Depende: r-cran-boot (>= 1.2.19) pero no va a instalarse
             Depende: r-cran-cluster (>= 1.9.6-2) pero no va a instalarse
             Depende: r-cran-foreign (>= 0.7-2) pero no va a instalarse
             Depende: r-cran-mgcv (>= 1.1.5) pero no va a instalarse
             Depende: r-cran-rpart (>= 3.1.20) pero no va a instalarse
             Depende: r-cran-survival (>= 2.13.2-1) pero no va a instalarse
             Depende: r-cran-mass pero no va a instalarse
             Depende: r-cran-class pero no va a instalarse
             Depende: r-cran-nnet pero no va a instalarse
             Depende: r-cran-codetools pero no va a instalarse
             Depende: r-cran-matrix pero no va a instalarse
```

Comment: Also, be aware of our sister site, [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), for Ubuntu-specific questions.

Comment: It looks like your issue is not actually with R, but with a different "stale" PPA that does not appear to provide packages for Ubuntu versions beyond (the EOL) 17.10